# .ipynb file does not exist in Jupyter even it does on Windows file explorer

Tags: windows-10, git, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have cloned a git repository that contains many Jupyter notebooks. However, some notebooks are non-existent on the Jupyter web file explorer that clearly exist on my Windows 10 file explorer. Others on my team who have Macs are able to clone the repo and see the files on Jupyter that are missing on my Windows machine. I'm wondering if it has anything to do with long path names? The reason I think this may have to do with file lengths is because I am unable to create new notebooks in the directory that have long file names. However, I am unsure how to fix this as I haven't seen other posts with the same issue. I did see a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows) that someone had asked about cloning git repositories and long path names, which worked for me (but the issue I am asking about is Jupyter specific). Any help is appreciated [Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC3cs.png) vs. [Windows 10 file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlytu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer to my own question. Basically it's a Windows issue and not a Jupyter issue. Windows 10 has a 260 character limit for file paths by default. Even though we enabled longpaths in my git settings, this only allowed git to pull in the full repo, but I guess windows still wasnt recognizing those files as legitimate. Basically, windows users need to go into the registry and change a value. That's it! See instructions on how to do that here: https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/